# PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 in Java

Tags: java, encryption, passwords, sha512, pbkdf2

Till now I have used "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1" for encrypting passwords. However, I recently thought that it would be better to upgrade to "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512" since it is considered a stronger algorithm.

However, Java does not support "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512" out of the box. I tried Googling but could come up with no definite solution.

Could you please tell me how can I encrypt passwords using "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512" in Java. It would be really helpful if you could provide code since I have limited idea about this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to upgrade? See [PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 Vs. PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11016)

Comment: [SunJCE supports PBKDF2withHMACSHA512.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider)